# How to serialize C array with NSCoding?

Tags: objective-c, nscoding

I have Objective-C class that has C array property.
And I want to serialize the property with NSCoding.

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject <NSCoding>
@property (nonatomic) int* intArray;
@end

@implementation TestClass
-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _intArray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            _intArray[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)dealloc
{
    free(_intArray);
}
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //???
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    //???
}
@end
```

What should I write in ???.
Thank you.

**EDIT:**
Thank you for answers.
But Which should I use decodeArrayOfObjCType:count:at: or NSData?
If I don't know count of array, I cannot use decodeArrayOfObjCType:count:at: method?

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _itemCount = [coder decodeIntForKey:kItemCount];
        _intArray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * _itemCount);
        [coder decodeArrayOfObjCType:@encode(int) count:_itemCount at:_intArray];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeInt:_itemCount forKey:kItemCount];
    [coder encodeArrayOfObjCType:@encode(int) count:_itemCount at:_intArray];
}
```

or

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _itemCount = [coder decodeIntForKey:kItemCount];
        NSData *data = [coder decodeObjectForKey:kIntArray];
        if (data) {
            NSUInteger length = [data length];
            _intArray = (int *)malloc(length);
            [data getBytes:_intArray length:length];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeInt:_itemCount forKey:kItemCount];
    if (_intArray) {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:_intArray length:sizeof(int) * _itemCount];
        [coder encodeObject:data forKey:kIntArray];
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know how many values are in the array at the time of decoding, then you might want to use `NSData`. So, you might have two properties, one for the `intData`, but another for the `count` of items in the array:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSData *data = [coder decodeObjectForKey:kIntArrayKey];
        if (data) {
            NSUInteger length = [data length];
            self.count = length / sizeof(int);
            self.intArray = (int *)malloc(length);
            [data getBytes:_intArray length:length];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    if (_intArray) {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:self.intArray length:sizeof(int) * self.count freeWhenDone:NO];
        [coder encodeObject:data forKey:kIntArrayKey];
    }
}
```

---

Or, if you didn't want to use `NSData`, you could use `encodeBytes:length:forKey:`:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSUInteger length;
        const uint8_t *bytes = [coder decodeBytesForKey:kIntArrayKey returnedLength:&length];
        if (bytes) {
            self.count = length / sizeof(int);
            self.intArray = (int *)malloc(length);
            memcpy(_intArray, bytes, length);
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    if (_intArray) {
        [coder encodeBytes:(void *)self.intArray length:sizeof(int) * self.count forKey:kIntArrayKey];
    }
}
```

---

The [Encoding and Decoding C Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingctypes.html) of the *Archives and Serializations Programming Guide* outlines some additional considerations:

> #### Arrays of Simple Types
>
> If you are encoding an array of bytes, you can just use the provided methods to do so.
>
> For other arithmetic types, create an `NSData` object with the array. Note that in this case, dealing with platform endianness issues is your responsibility. Platform endianness can be handled in two general ways. The first technique is to convert the elements of the array (or rather, a temporary copy of the array) into a canonical endianness, either big or little, one at a time with the functions discussed in Swapping Bytes in Universal Binary Programming Guidelines, Second Edition (see also “Byte Ordering” in [*Foundation Functions Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003774)) and give that result to the `NSData` as the buffer. (Or, you can write the bytes directly with `encodeBytes:length:forKey:`.) At decode time, you have to reverse the process, converting from the big or little endian canonical form to the current host representation. The other technique is to use the array as-is and record in a separate keyed value (perhaps a boolean) which endianness the host was when the archive was created. During decoding, read the endian key and compare it to the endianness of the current host and swap the values only if different.
>
> Alternatively, you can archive each array element separately as their native type, perhaps by using key names inspired by the array syntax, like `“theArray[0]”`, `“theArray[1]”`, and so on. This is not a terribly efficient technique, but you can ignore endian issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I don't know count of array at decode time, then I cannot use decodeArrayOfObjCType:count:at: method? Please read my edited comment. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how you can use `decodeArrayOfObjCType` unless you know the `count` in advance. That's why I suggested `encodeObject` approach. You can use `encodeBytes`, too.

Comment: @noprops just encode the count first, before encoding the items in the array. Then when you decode, you decode the count first and after that you know how many there are.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert But `decodeArrayOfObjCType` doesn't take a `key`. How do you encode multiple values when one of them doesn't take a key?

Comment: @Rob there are no keys if you use `NSCoding` directly. Keys only exist if you use `NSKeyedArchiver` which is not required. Note that `decodeArrayOfObjCType` is part of `NSCoding` and does not exist in `NSKeyedArchiver`.  `NSCoding` will just give you the next value each time you decode something, in the same order as you encoded it.

Comment: Personally, I only ever work with C arrays when I need high performance and/or low memory consumption. In those situations it is better to use `NSCoding` directly and avoid using `NSKeyedArchiver` or `NSData`. While those do provide a nice high level abstraction, at that point I wouldn't be using a C array at all - I'd use `NSArray`.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert I see your point, though I don't agree that the choice to use C array means that one should necessarily abandon keyed archives. One has nothing to do with the other. Also, if you don't like using `NSData`, you could use `encodeBytes:length:forKey:`. But thanks for clarifying your comments!

Comment: @Rob I have nothing against NSData. The last time NSArray was too slow, I tried a C array but quickly rewrote it to use NSData, using getBytes to read values from the "array". My problem is with copying bytes into NSData temporarily then copying it into the archive. That doubles both your execution time and RAM consumption for no reason.

Comment: Obviously, you can also use `dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:` if you don't want it to copy the data when archiving.

Answer (score 4):

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _intArray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
        [coder decodeArrayOfObjCType:@encode(int) count:5 at:_intArray];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [coder encodeArrayOfObjCType:@encode(int) count:5 at:_intArray];
}
```