# How to save an array of Int64 variables using NSCoding in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am currently using NSCoding to save an array of Int variables like this:

```
var myArray = [Int]()

myArray = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("MyArray") as! [(Int)]

aCoder.encodeObject(myArray, forKey: "MyArray")
```

I now need to save an array of Int64 variables. I thought it would be simple, so I did this:

```
var myNewArray = [Int64]()

myNewArray = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("MyNewArray") as! [(Int64)]

aCoder.encodeObject(myNewArray, forKey: "MyNewArray")
```

However I get an error on the last line:
    Cannot convert value of type '[Int64]' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'

I am puzzled as to why it works with Int but not Int64. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at [How can I get an NSCoder to encode/decode a Swift array of structs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865202/how-can-i-get-an-nscoder-to-encode-decode-a-swift-array-of-structs) for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current version of Swift, when you convert `[Int]` to `AnyObject` (or `AnyObject?`), Swift generates `NSArray` containing `NSNumber`s. Although `NSNumber` can contain `Int64` (`long long int` in C/Objective-C), Swift does not convert `Int64` to `NSNumber` automatically, thus, `[Int64]` cannot be automatically converted to `AnyObject`.

You can generate an `NSArray` containing `NSNumber` explicitly.

```
let myI64Array = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("MyNewArray") as! [NSNumber]
myNewArray = myI64Array.map{$0.longLongValue}
```

Or:

```
let myI64Array = myNewArray.map{NSNumber(longLong: $0)}
aCoder.encodeObject(myI64Array, forKey: "MyNewArray")
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am puzzled as to why it works with Int but not Int64. How can I achieve this?

It doesn't actually work with Int either. You have to have an array of Objective-C *objects*, and a number is not an object in Objective-C.

However, Swift *bridges* Int to NSNumber automatically, so it *looks* like it works.

It doesn't do that for Int64. You have to create the NSNumber objects yourself.